# How to run mosh in a python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, mosh

I'm struggling to run mosh effectively within a python subprocess.  I can spin up a mosh client and connect to a mosh server, but the process appears to hang.

example ssh command:

```
ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR -l username server_dns_name
```

example mosh command:

```
mosh --ssh="ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR -l username" server_dns_name
```

python invocation:

```
import subprocess

# command = "ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR -l username server_dns_name"
command = "mosh --ssh=\"ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR -l username\" server_dns_name"

proc = subprocess.run(command, env=os.environ, shell=True)
```

---

I expect: *normal interaction with mosh.*

I get: *no way to interact, but a screen presents itself as if I'm connected.*

What am I missing?

Comment: There's no reason to use `shell=True` here; pass the list `["mosh", "--ssh=ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR -l username", "server_dns_name"]` as the first argument instead.

Comment: A shell adds one more moving part than you would have without one -- extra complexity means more potential things that could be going wrong (f/e, any script named in an environment variable named `ENV` is executed during shell startup, *before* the shell gets around to invoking your copy of `mosh`). Not that that's a high likelihood source of your bug here, but the simpler the better.

Comment: BTW, `env=os.environ` is completely pointless -- the default if you don't pass `env` at all is to inherit the parent process's environment.

Comment: Is this a REPL session or a script? Does connecting the child's stdin, stdout and stderr explicitly to handles on `/dev/tty` (and closing the parent's copies first, if they are in fact directed there) have any effect?

Comment: (Another note -- if you don't need the `--ssh` argument to reproduce the issue, and can test that it reproduces without same, a proper [mcve] would take it out).

Comment: ...so, I can't reproduce this myself. ```python3.6 -c 'import subprocess, sys; command = ["mosh", sys.argv[1]]; proc = subprocess.run(command)' myhost``` behaves identically to running `mosh` directly. No difference when I add `"--ssh=ssh -o SendEnv=ENVVAR"` either.

Comment: (...as an aside, I strongly advise against using `shlex.split()` when you could instead be hardcoding an explicit argv -- like a shell, it's an abstraction layer that's adding complexity without any benefit for same; passing an explicit list is what the OS actually does under-the-hood when it invokes the `execve()` syscall, so if you want to have as much as control as possible over what's *actually* going on when you invoke a program, an explicit list is the way to go).

Comment: Without using shell=True, there's no issue.  Can someone explain why shell=True is a problem?